Getting same address on multiple chains
I am attempting to use Forge to deploy a token on both Sepolia & Avax test net.
The nonce on the networks are different, so I am trying to force the nonce.
My commands:
forge script script/"$contract".s.sol:"$contract"Script --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_HTTP_RPC_URL" --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY" --broadcast --verify --optimize 200
nonce=$(cast nonce "$WALLET_ADDRESS" --rpc-url "$SEPOLIA_HTTP_RPC_URL")
forge script script/"$contract".s.sol:"$contract"Script --rpc-url "$AVAX_HTTP_RPC_URL" --private-key "$PRIVATE_KEY" --nonce "$nonce" --broadcast --verify --optimize 200

But when I run it I get this error:
forge script script/PigfoxToken.s.sol:PigfoxTokenScript --rpc-url https://api.avax-test.network/ext/bc/C/rpc --private-key xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx --nonce 2363 --broadcast --verify --optimize 200
error: unexpected argument '--nonce' found

Any idea how to set the same nonce for both networks or another way to deploy a contract and get the same address o  both networks?

The easiest way to ensure the same nonce results in the same contract address after deployment on different networks is to use a fresh account for the deployment.
Simply create a fresh account, fund it with enough native tokens on each network to cover the gas fees for deployment, and ensure that the first transaction made with that account is the contract deployment on each network.
